# Suitable animation software and/or app for computer science animations

Tags: osx, ios, animation

I'm looking for Mac software and/or iOS apps to easily create educational animations for computer science. I want to be able to scribble with my mouse (or hopefully iPad using Astropad to move the mouse cursor), draw rectangles and circles, type text, and record audio directly in the program, and edit using a timeline style interface.  Ideally I would be able to move a project between an iPad and the Mac, make objects move, and be able to change or rerecord elements without impacting things already recorded afterwards.   I have recorded several videos with Explain Everything for iPad, but the ability to do retroactive editing is surprisingly limited in practice (I know this is hard, but it isn't impossible) and due to some personal physical constraints it's hard for me to use an iPad for long.  I have tried screen casting programs such as Camtasia Mac, but they only do drawing as annotation and it's clunky.  Browser-based software is also acceptable.

Comment: Here is a similar thread I found that's more Windows-oriented:  https://www.reddit.com/r/VideoEditing/comments/3v5e0t/animation_noob_looking_for_free_software_to_do/

Comment: I'm hoping to find someone who does this kind of thing a lot and can say they've tried multiple alternatives and what they've settled on.  I have considered Adobe Captivate but am concerned about the steep learning curve and $30/mo subscription.

Comment: I've also tried simply recording myself standing at a whiteboard.  That works but is very time-consuming to produce.

Comment: Powerpoint and Keynote have been recommended but I haven't tried them yet since they lack a timeline and I presume narration and exporting to video are rudimentary.  Keynote also lacks a free drawing tool (does do on iOS but only as temporary annotation and not "first-class object").

Comment: I'm hoping to find someone who does this kind of thing a lot and can say they've tried multiple alternatives and what they've settled on. I have considered Adobe Captivate but am concerned about the steep learning curve and having read at some places that it's slow to use.  I need fast and easy more than professional.

Comment: Please add all your comments as an [edit] to your question, then remove them. Your question also tends towards a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text), please fix that.